# Inserting a folder containing specific routes to a bottle application in Python

Tags: python, bottle

Let us say that we have the following directory structure ...

```
+-- main.py
|
+--+ ./web
|  |
|  +--- ./web/bottleApp.py
```

Currently, I want to organize the files so that the I can separate different functionality in different areas.  Template `main.py` and `./web/bottleApp.py` look like the following ...

This is the `./web/bottleApp.py` file:

```
import bottle

app = bottle.Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def root():    
    return 'This is the root application'
# some additional functions here ...
```

And this is the `main.py` file ...

```
from web import bottleApp as app 

with app.app as report:
    # Some random routes here ...
    report.run(host = 'localhost', port=8080)
```

Now I want to add another folder which can handle some functions which I may optionally use is a bunch of my projects, (for example configuration file handling via the web interface just created)

Let us say we want to insert the following folder/file configuration ...

```
+-- main.py
|
+--+ ./web
|  |
|  +--- ./web/bottleApp.py
|
+--+ ./configure
   | 
   +--- ./configure/config.py
```

Given the original `app = bottle.Bottle()` I want to create the following sample route in the file `./configure/config.py`:

```
@app.route('/config/config1')
def config1():
    return 'some config data'
```

How do I even go about doing this? Once I run the `main.py` file, how do I make sure that the other routes are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bottle can run multiple bottle apps as a single instance.
You can use something like this on main.py

```
import bottle
from web.bottleApp import app
from configure.config import configure_app

main = bottle.Bottle()
main.mount("/config/",configure)
main.mount("/",app)

main.run(host = 'localhost', port=8080)
```

and on configure/config.py something like this:

```
import bottle

config_app = bottle.Bottle()

@config_app.route('/config1')
def config1():    
    return 'some config data'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a *much* better solution than I was hoping for!